# LibreOffice Calc: Formatting Time is adding ' char

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have some data in calc like so:

```
05:00:27
01:27:02
07:29:57
06:22:01
```

I select the cells, and right click 'format cells', and choose `Time -> 876613:37:46`.  When I do this, it adds an apostrophe to the beginning of each cell, so the data ends up like this:

```
'05:00:27
'01:27:02
'07:29:57
'06:22:01
```

Why is that?  How can I prevent it?

Comment: The problem is that if your cell contain "05:00:27", they are already formatted. Without formatting, the content would be "0,208645833333333" in case of "05:00:27". So, the answer depends on the "real" content of you cell. To check this, remove any "direct formatting" using Menu "Format" -> "Clear direct formatting", or using CTRL+M.

Answer (score 0):

Very often the time value is presented as a string
ie. appears as '01:00:00
when formatted as time.

There are two solutions to this:

1. To delete the single quote. This is extremely tedious if there are more values
2. To create another cell which uses a formula to convert to timevalue.
   If eg A1 contains '01:00:00 then create another cell with =TIMEVALUE(A1), the formula can be dragged along to easily convert multiple values